# creating mobile List (iOs, android) in AS3 using external XML?

Tags: android, ios, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a mobile app in adobe air as3. currently I need to create a list in the application using an external XML file which would allow users to click items in the list etc.

I fond MadComponents which would allow you to create Lists using AS3 but the issue that I have is it seems like that MadComponents only allows you to create the List using hard coded inside the AS3 and not an external XML file!

so basically in a sense, you cannot use MadComponents to create a dynamic List as everything is set within the AS3 code and no external XML file can be used!

are there any other easy options out there?

or is it possible to use MadComponents with an external XML file?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @moot, i know how to load xml data into flash. my question mainly was about ios/android list using xml....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I create a list from an External XML file, I load the XML file into the AS3 application using a FileStream.  You can then parse the information into an Array of Objects that you can then parse into a list.  This allows for the XML file to change and the information always be up to date, but the same process can be followed to display information given from an API.

Are you using Flex Framework, or straight AS3?

Comment: I'm using AS3... i know how to load XML data into AS3 APPLICATION but I need to use the iOs/android list to display the data! its not like a simple flash list etc....

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding of the problem.  I understand what you are looking for.  I found some help information from the Mad Components page about how to populate a list.                                                         var list:UIList = UIList(UI.findViewById("list"));
list.data = [{label:”one”}, {label:”two”}, {label:”three”}];
list.data = [“one”,”two”,”three”];
list.xmlData = <data><one/><two/><three/></data>;
list.xmlData = <data><i label=”one”/><i label=”two”/></data>;

Comment: You will need to load the data from the XML Document into the list.xmlData, and that should populate the list. I've included the link to the document in case you don't have it https://code.google.com/p/mad-components/downloads/detail?name=madCode0_5_5.pdf&can=2&q=

Comment: I've accepted this answer as its clear and informative. I've contacted Madcomponents developers and they said we can use external XML files in madcomponents but this will have its down sides i.e. we will lose the functionality of {} example( <list>{DATA}</list>. Just a head up, if you are looking to develop and expand on your project, keep clear of madcomponents as it will only limit your development and also creates alot more hassle in a long run. and as its provided as an open source, there is no "REAL" help or support so you are all on your own. best to create your own features. Good luck